# Debugging TLS handshake failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to access my peer through the `fabric-network` nodejs sdk.

However, I encounter an error during the `gateway.connect` in the sdk and the logs I find in the peer container is not helpful.

All I have, even with the `grpc=debug` logging mode is :

```sh
peer0.catie-test      | 2020-09-21 13:27:07.731 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 087 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: handshake failure server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:49918
peer0.catie-test      | 2020-09-21 13:27:07.731 UTC [grpc] handleRawConn -> DEBU 088 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "172.17.0.1:49918": remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

Any way to have more helpful logs ? I would like to know, for example, which key are used for the TLS handshake check.

---

**Edit with more infos:** Configuration files and TLS verification

My peer is configured with TLS with the env variables :

```sh
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls-msp/keystore/key.pem
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.catie-test-cert.pem
```

I have the correct tlscacert of my peer on the client side, because the output from the peer and from client side are the same:

```sh
cat /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.catie-test-cert.pem  # From the peer, output ZTd/o8LLw== at the end
cat /tmp/fabric-start-catie-test/building/artifacts/peer0.catie-test-crypto/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.catie-test-cert.pem  # From the client, output ZTd/o8LLw== at the end
```

Path to the peer tlscacert is filled in the client side connection-profile.json :

```json
"peers": {
        "peer0.catie-test": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/tmp/fabric-start-catie-test/building/artifacts/peer0.catie-test-crypto/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.catie-test-cert.pem"
            },
            "grpcOptions":{
                "ssl-target-name-override": "172.17.0.7",
                "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 10000
            },
            "url": "grpcs://172.17.0.4:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://172.17.0.4:7053"
        }
    }
```

And I also checked that the tlsCAcert is the one that generated my peer cert :

```sh
openssl verify -CAfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE $CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE  # Output : /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls-msp/signcerts/cert.pem: OK
```

---

**Edit 2 :** Grpc option, peer name instead of IP and client logs

Also tried adding the `grpcOptions` to the `peer` section of the `connection-profile.json` (see the updated paragraph above) but it didn't change anything.

Also tried to add peer name to my `/etc/hosts` to reach my peer via its name instead of its IP. It makes a warning disappear but don't solve my problem and I prefer to work with IPs in my scripts.

Here are the logs of the nodejs sdk client in case it helps to diagnose the problem, but it only says that the `Endorser must be connected` and I think it is, because it reaches my peer as I have this TLS error in my peer's logs.

```sh
(node:59350) [DEP0123] DeprecationWarning: Setting the TLS ServerName to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066. This will be ignored in a future version.
2020-09-23T06:42:20.704Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.catie-test, url:grpcs://172.17.0.7:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-23T06:42:20.705Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.catie-test url:grpcs://172.17.0.7:7051 timeout:3000
2020-09-23T06:42:20.708Z - error: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser peer0.catie-test due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.catie-test, url:grpcs://172.17.0.7:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
    at checkState (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:69:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:292:17)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  connectFailed: true
}
(node:59350) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Endorser must be connected
    at Channel.addEndorser (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/Channel.js:259:10)
    at buildChannel (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/ccp/networkconfig.js:50:21)
    at Object.loadFromConfig (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/ccp/networkconfig.js:34:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Gateway.connect (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/gateway.js:279:13)
    at async queryChaincode (/home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/test/chaincode-sdk/index.js:41:5)
    at async /home/rqueraud/CATIE/Myrmica/myrmica-start/test/chaincode-sdk/index.js:57:5
```

---

**Edit 3 :** Docker IPs ? Trying with EC2 instances.

As @Urko mentionned, my nodes are in fact docker container running docker-in-docker (dind) images. Inside these containers are some other containers running the hyperledger peers, cli, ... images.

I access them from the host which is also where I run the fabric sdk nodejs client. I cannot access them via their container name, I think it is only possible in a docker-compose configuration, isn't it ? I already tried (see Edit 2 above) to add their name to my /etc/hosts to reach them via a name instead of an IP but it didn't change anything.

However, as my network startup is scripted, I deployed it using docker-machine in AWS instead of the dind docker containers this time, so these are real instances reachable on the internet. But I still encounter the same errors, here is the log from the peer where you can see this is coming from a public IP :

```sh
2020-09-24 08:32:57.653 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0d7 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: handshake failure server=PeerServer remoteaddress=31.36.26.4:35462
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the connection with your Peer have been defined to be secured by the TLS protocol. So, you may configure you Peer configuration to know wich certificates are you using at the TLS.

As when you connect to any server using this protocol, the communication among the parties is encripted using the certificate of the server (in this case, the Peer will be the server). So, you need to configure your client to trust on the server by the Root CA that haven been used to issue the Peers TLS certificates.

The client is where you use the SDK, so, you should configure it to trust on the Peer TLS certificate. When you configure the connection to the Blockchain nodes (peers and orderers), you would define their direction, as well as their TLS certificate. This one is an example that you can find at the following [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html). There, you have to define the value of the tlsCACerts param:

```
orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
      grpc-max-send-message-length: 4194304
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tlscacerts/example.com-cert.pem
peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tlscacerts/org1.example.com-cert.pem
```

*----- Edited ----*

Also, you have to check the value of the `ssl-target-name-override` param. It should be the same to you nodes name, as you can see in the example file

*----- Edited ----*

Why are you using those IPs?! I understand that those IPs are internal from the Docker network, so you should not use them. Could you try using your containers names instead of the docker networks IPs?

*----- Edited ----*

Could you verify your `ca-server` configuration file and check that the `tls` is set to true?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question with more details and even the peer section of my `connection-profile.yaml`. It looks like yours.

Comment: Hi, I tried the `ssl-target-name-override`, with IP and with the name, still no success. I updated my question (Edit 2) with the details.

Comment: Hi @Romain! I have also edited my answer. I think that you are using the docker IPs incorrectly

Comment: Hi @Urko ! You're right, these are docker containers and docker IPs. But it doesn't seem to be the problem unfortunately... You can see what I tried in my updated question below the *Edit 3* section.

Comment: How did you create your TLS certificates? Using the CA? Did you checked the name of the host for them? Could you try again putting the peer name at the ssl-target-name-override?

Comment: Hi @Urko, I got it to work :D. Yes they were created using the ca-server. I was overriding the ca-server configuration file and tls was set to false in this file. I reset configuration to default and it works great now ! 
Thanks for the help you gave me for debugging this ! Can you include the conclusion in your answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Hi Romain! Done!. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You try a gRPC call in peer Server where peer server is secured with it's TLS system. So if you fail to provide the valid TLS certificate, server tls handshake will be failed and you will not get success to establish the connection.

Please check that your network config file is properly develop, also check that you are using the same TLS certificate that is used to run the peer server and your TLS certificate path is correct.

Comment: I think that I used the same TLS certificate, I edited my question with details on how I did that.